# Menu item selected in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question..I need to make a option of menu selected...
My html:

```
<ul class="ca-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/home.png"></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">Home</h2>
                            <h3 class="ca-sub">Home</h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/about.png"></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">About</h2>
                            <h3 class="ca-sub">About</h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/photo.png"></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">contact</h2>
                            <h3 class="ca-sub">Contact/h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
```

And my css

```
.ca-menu li:hover{
background-color: #000;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
color: #ff2020;
-webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
-moz-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
-ms-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
 }
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
 color: #000;
-webkit-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
-moz-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;

-ms-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
color: #000;
background-color: #ff2020;
-webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
-moz-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
-ms-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li a").click(function(event){
        $('#navigation li').removeClass();
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I must add a active class for li:hover in my css?I do not want to change anything because I want the hover to remain the same..Help me please

Comment: jQuery that you have tried ???

Comment: Yes:
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("li a").click(function(event){
           $('#navigation li').removeClass();
           $(this).parent().addClass('active');   
           event.preventDefault();
          
      });
  });
But where I need to add active class?

Comment: what problem with this code...? should work..

Answer (score 0):

Question is a little ambiguous. If you mean "how do I style the active page's menu item so it is different from the other items in the menu:

A way to do this is have a class on the `html` or `body` tag and then style the menu accordingly. e.g.

```
<body class="section-home">
...
<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li class="menu-home"> ....
```

So the home page would have class `section-home` all pages in about would have `section-about`

and the css would be something like

```
.section-home .menu-home,
.section-about menu-about,
...
{ 
    <active styling>
}
```

This does work well on simple sites (I have used it for years and years) but may become unwieldy if you have a CMS that adds the menu items dynamically.

Good Luck

### Alternate issue

If the question means, how can I style the page on hover, why are you doing this with jQuery, most can be done with CSS.

What browsers are you supporting?

- IE9+ and recent chrome / ff?
- what about mobile browsers - you cannot hover on mobile - will the site still work

Lots to think about, and once again, good luck.

Comment: I dont't understand how,but I'll try

Comment: Great ... oh and I'd put the hover on the `a` not the `li` as really old IE will then support it

Comment: Ruskin,you can help me with this example..I do not understand well ;)

Comment: Create a dummy page on codepen.io or another similar site with your code. Tell us exactly what your intentions are and we can try to steer you in the right direction.